# Can't close the app from a Dialog?

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I have the next code, where I can't put a `finish();` when I press "OK" `Button`(into a `Dialog`).

```
public void showAlertDialog(Context context, String title, String message,
    Boolean status) {
    AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context).create();

    // Setting Dialog Title
    alertDialog.setTitle(title);

    // Setting Dialog Message
    alertDialog.setMessage(message);

    if(status != null)
        // Setting alert dialog icon
       alertDialog.setIcon((status) ? R.drawable.success : R.drawable.fail);

    // Setting OK Button
    alertDialog.setButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        }

    });

    // Showing Alert Message
    alertDialog.show();

}   
}
```

What it's wrong? I mean, I don't understand so much, I am newbie, but I just don't want the solution, I want too the explanation if it's possible, please.

Comment: Explain *why* you "can't" put `finish()` there. What is/isn't happening? Errors?

Comment: @codeMagic Yep, i get errors :/

"The method finish() is undefined for the type new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){}"

PS: I am not in my "main" activity.

Comment: Yep, then that's your problem. You either need to pass a reference to your activity or create a callback to the actiivty

Comment: `getActivity().finish()` *may* work, depending on the type of class you're working with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

finish() only can finish Activity.But you want to close your application then finsih() will not work. for this you have to call this method.

```
alertDialog.dismiss();    
System.exit(0);
```

Answer (score 1):

The possible explanation is that this function is not in your activity class. If so you will have to acquire the instance of your activity in this class . For example if it is mActivity  Then use
`mActivity.finish()`  in your show function.

Comment: lol, i though that was for that reason but negative.
Put this: "AlertDialogManager.finish();" AlertDialogManager.java is the class. And i get this error: "The method finish() is undefined for the type AlertDialogManager".
Tried doing finish a method but i dont get for what it's exactly. (and doesn't worked)

Comment: Then please post your whole class.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to close an app from a dialog you can, but finish() would only finish() the current Activity? Try System.exit(0); with a listener callback to the Activity.

```
interface Listener{
    onOK();
}
Dialog{
    onClick(){
        Listener.onOK();
    }
}
Activity implements Listener{
    onOK(){
        this.finish();
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you have the `Context` from your `Activity`, cast that to `Activity` and call `finish()` on it

```
alertDialog.setButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        ((Activity)context).finish();
    }
```

Doing this you would need to make `context` final or make it a member variable of whichever class this is in.